# PHP using file() to read in file in subdirectory

Tags: javascript, php, file

Running PHP5+ on NGINX Server.  I am reading a file into an array using PHP file().  I have a PHP/Javascript function that works **perfectly** when the file I am reading in is in the **same** directory.  Code:

```
var attribute = [<?php 
    $data = file("ATTRIBS.txt");
    $n = count($data);
    for ($v = 1; $v <= $n; $v++) {
        print '"'.trim($data[$v-1]).'",';
    }?>];
```

However, in the final version, I want to have multiple ATTRIBS files in a subfolder, "/sysBuilds".

If I change the file() line to read

```
$data = file("sysBuilds/ATTRIBS.txt");
```

or /sysBuilds or /var/www/html/sysBuilds...  the function fails to pick up the data in the file.  I've seen things about FILE_INCLUDE_PATH but none of it (at least to me with my current level of understanding) seems to make any sense or fit what I am trying to do.  I'm sure this is an easy issue but I'm just not recognizing what I need to be able to recognize what the answer is here...  appreciate some guideance.  Thanks.

EDIT:  Permissions and error log output:

```
2018/03/28 21:16:40 [error] 805#0: *129 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  file(./HostBuilds/ATTRIBS.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/BehaviorPad.php on line 159" while reading upstream, client: 192.168.1.3, server: 192.168.1.201, request: "GET /BehaviorPad.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "192.168.1.201"
```

Perms:

```
/sysBuilds drwxrw-rw-
/sysBuilds/ATTRIBS.txt -rwxrw-rw-
BehaviorPad.php -rwxrwxrwx
```

UPDATE:  FIGURED IT OUT.  Never expected that the /sysBuilds directory needed execute perms to allow the file() method to run.  Thanks!

Comment: make sure all folders have the right permissions, not just the files and this for both reading and writing.  What does error reporting show?

Comment: I've ensured I have r & w on all files & the directory.  See above for file & folder perms - I went overkill just to be sure...

Comment: Thanks Funk! Appreciate the nudge in the right direction, even though I couldn't imagine the subdir needing x perms...  error log I forgot about as well.  Just getting into this part of all this.

Comment: you're welcome, glad I could help.

Comment: btw, Stack does let you post your own answer, as an quick "FYI".  For all your questions too. Editing your post(s) doesn't really qualify as an answer, there is a spot below for it, and accept it when it lets you. *cheers*